# Is it possible to make two models in a single controller in mean stack?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am new to the MEAN STACK and I am being asked to complete a project on the entry and exit of a user. The username of every user is stored in another collection. So, I want 2 models in a single module using the MEAN stack. Is it possible to make two models in a single module? I am using mongodb as the back end.

Kindly give a response. Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is yes, you are able to create more than one model in a module.  The long answer requires more information about what you are doing, what you have so far, and what your specific problem may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can call more than one Model & perform your queries,
Even you can try 2 collections in one collection.

Read About nested collections in MongoDB/Mongoose 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html